# How do I get the count of the different elements between two same elements in Python?

Tags: python

I have a scenario:

```
dm_connect
dm_logon_failure
dm_logon_failure
dm_logon_failure
dm_logon_failure
dm_login
dm_connect
dm_logon_failure
dm_logon_failure
dm_logon_failure
dm_logon_failure
dm_login
dm_connect
```

Here I need to get the count between one dm_connect to another dm_connect using Python program. How to do this?

Comment: please be more specific. how is the input given? what would be the output? more importantly, what did you do so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using `str.split()`.

**Ex:**

```
s = """dm_connect
dm_logon_failure
dm_logon_failure
dm_logon_failure
dm_logon_failure
dm_login
dm_connect
dm_logon_failure
dm_logon_failure
dm_logon_failure
dm_logon_failure
dm_login
dm_connect"""

print([len(i.strip().splitlines()) for i in filter(None, s.split("dm_connect"))])
```

**Output:**

```
[5, 5]
```